# Why the users email is override by [email protected]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why the users email is override by [email protected]?

```
public function scopeGetList($query)
{
    $users = $query->where("account_id",Auth::user()->account_id)
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->get(array('id','name','email'));

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $data\[$user->id\] = sprintf("%s - %s",$user->name,$user->email);
    }

    return $data;

}
```

[image: Print]

[image: Model]

Any Help?

Comment: What are you trying to archive. Your question is not clear

Comment: Please print your user model, I think you set up a variable called email being private.

Comment: mimo, i update post with model print, the email is not private , the remaining code not set any behavior on email property.

Comment: Try making use of the [properties](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) `fillable` and `guarded` which allow you to specify which fields to update and which ones not touch at all respectively.

Answer (score 15):

Thank´s for all.

I discovery the problem is a feature turned on on cloudflare.

[image]

Comment: Life saver! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

These is about changing to query `scopeGetList`. You have to change the into this:

```
public function scopeGetList($query)
{
    $data = array();
    $users = $query->where("account_id",Auth::user()->account_id)
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->get();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $data[[$user->id]] = $user['name'] + " - "+ $user['email']);
    }

    return $data;

}
```

I hope this help you.